# How does one add a custom iCloud Drive folder to the Finder Favorites sidebar?

Tags: finder, icloud, macos

Recently, I upgraded to iCloud Drive and began storing a number of files in it. I created a new folder in iCloud Drive (not one of the default "Pages" or "TextEdit" folders) and put my files in it. However, because I use it so frequently, I would like to put the folder in my Finder sidebar. When I tried to do so, it would not allow me — it simply gave me the option to drag it into an existing folder in the sidebar. It did not even display the circle with the cross through it ("do not enter sign," if you will) that often appears when I attempt to drag a folder to the Favorites bar that cannot be added. However, I was able to add the default iCloud Drive folders ("Keynote," "Preview") to the Favorites sidebar without any issues. I have also tried CMD-dragging to create an alias on the sidebar, but to no avail.

I'm running a late 2013 iMac on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to create a temporary alias of your new folder.

1. Create a folder in iCloud Drive.
2. Right-click the folder and select `Make Alias`.
3. Drag-and-drop the alias folder (little black arrow on folder symbol) into your sidebar.
4. You can now delete the alias folder (**NOT** in the sidebar).

Hope this helps, if not leave a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Finder -> Preference -> Sidebar -> Check iCloud. All your iCloud folders can now be accessed from the favorites in side bar.

Answer (score 0):

It is even easier:
any folder that you have (created), just drag it to the sidebar: it will stay where it is, and appears in the sidebar. When you right click it in the sidebar you can remove it (the folder stays where it is).

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do, which hasn't been working.